# Display regular property and expanded property at the same time

Tags: powershell-3.0

I need to display two properties: one is called DisplayName and second is HostName (under MasterCoreInfo property).

The script is working, but I'm trying to combine it in the same result and 1 line command.
So far so bad.

```
powershell -Command "get-replicatedservers -core localhost:8006 | select DisplayName | format-list"

Outputs:
DisplayName : server2
DisplayName : server3

powershell -Command "get-replicatedservers -core localhost:8006 | select -expand MasterCoreInfo | select HostName | format-list"

Outputs:
HostName : remote3
HostName : remote4
```

All I'm trying to do is to combine two results, so HostName and DisplayName will be in the same list corresponding each server. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation doesn't state it, it appears that the `-Property` and `-Expandproperty` parameters for `select-object` are mutually exclusive, with `-expandproperty` taking precedence.

You'll need to either change the output of `get-replicatedservers`, or process those two properties separately, compiling them into a custom `PSObject` that contains the data you want. To do this, pipe the output of `get-replicatedservers` into a `foreach-object` block and work on them there.